# How to handle routes by VueJS in ASP.NET core using Endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

Am trying to create a VueJS SPA with ASP.NET core in the backend

Since `dotnet SDK` version `3.0.100` no longer supports Vue, I created a React app

```
dotnet new react
```

and swapped the `ClientApp` with a Vue app

```
rm -rf ClientApp
vue create frontend
```

Everything works perfectly except for 1 thing

Whenever I launch the app http://localhost:5000 and click on any Vue Router link, say http://localhost:5000/about (it works) but if I refresh I get an **expected** 404

> Cannot GET /about

Same goes if I typed the URL into the browser and access directly

It's worth noting that the default React app doesn't face this problem, I compared everything between the files of the two ASP.NET apps using [this tool](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) and found no differences

Now Vue Router handles routes by Javascript because it's using the #!hash behind the scenes, so ASP.NET router tries to match the URL to an AboutController@index which doesn't exist hence the 404

Researching revealed that I should set a wildcard fallback to the SPA router in `Startup.cs`, but all the answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41247191/5581565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50601878/5581565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663881/5581565), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34708085/5581565), [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47988721/5581565), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35325849/5581565) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56094371/5581565) are using `app.UseMvc()` and I don't have that enabled, I am using `app.UseEndpoints` instead

I also tried searching GitHub but same [results](https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template/blob/master/content/AspNetCore.VueJs/Startup.cs#L42)

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57705878/5581565) recommends I stick to `app.UseEndPoints` and [Microsoft migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) too

[The Vue Router Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) talks about this very issue and proposes a solution for .NET apps using `web.config` for IIS like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602061/5581565) but am running Kestrel server on a Linux machine so this takes no effect

Here's my `Startup.cs` file

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;

namespace spa
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the Vue files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "frontend/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "frontend";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "serve:bs");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I pushed this app to [GitHub here](https://github.com/CaddyDz/spa) to make it easy to reproduce just in case I forgot something

How can I achieve the same effect of this

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback", "{*anything}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

using `app.UseEndpoints`?

---

Just in case this is relevant, here's my Vue router

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import NotFound from './views/NotFound.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            // route level code-splitting
            // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
            // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
            component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/forecast',
            name: 'forecast',
            component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "forecast" */ './views/Forecast.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            component: NotFound
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to solve this?

Comment: @FrodeLillerud yes, see [this repo](https://github.com/CaddyDz/spa)

Comment: try this repo https://github.com/SoftwareAteliers/asp-net-core-vue-starter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this template https://github.com/SoftwareAteliers/asp-net-core-vue-starter. It's recently updated and support .Net Core 3.0 and Vue CLI 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I added a call to the `MapFallbackToFile()` method available in .NET 6 to solve my Vue3 Routing issue. (Using `vue-router` version 4.)  Any route Url not found in my Controllers maps back to the default Index action in the Default controller (which is essentially the same as the Vue app's  index.html SPA landing page). This way route urls defined in Vue will work properly.

`app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Default"); \\ Program.cs`

Rather than mapping back to a controller, you can also map back to the `index.html` file described in and described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414397/asp-net-core-mvc-catch-all-route-serve-static-file/75151981#75151981).

`app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");`